# Does an android phone unroot itself on factory reset?

Tags: rooting

If you root your android device, and then factory restore it... does it remain rooted?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. you need to Root after Factory Reset

also, and if you want to unroot then remove busybox, remove files in /system/xbin folder, and in SuperSU application in Options, Choose Uninstall

Comment: This is not correct. Root binaries are put in `/system`, unless you use some kind of very unusual root method, and `/system` is not erased by a factory reset. You wouldn't need to re-root unless you somehow moved your root app (Superuser, SuperSU) to a user app on `/data` (but there's no reason to do that).

Comment: From what i learned i need to Root Again.. maybe im wrong, please correct me